# In MySQL, is "WHERE column LIKE 'abc%'" considered a range scan, for the purpose of indexing?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Say I have a query like this:

```
SELECT column1, date FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE 'abc%' AND date > '2015-01-01'
```

If I have an index on (column1, date), will it use the index as a covering index? Usually, a range column must be last in a multi-column index, because the following columns can't be used in constraints.

I cannot find anything in the documentation regarding this. It seems to me that the explain plan shows far too many rows that need to be looked up, even though it should be a covering index.

EDIT: will show the real query:

```
SELECT
  count(*) AS cnt,
  `col1`
FROM table
USE INDEX (table_col2_col1_date_index)
WHERE `col1` IN ('25485') AND `col2` LIKE 'text-%' AND `date` > '2016-06-03 18:13:40'
GROUP BY `col1`;
```

As you can see, my index covers all three columns. Explain says:

> Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

Explain shows `38069776` rows to examine. Doing a `count(*)` for `col2 like 'text-%'` shows 20427133. So assuming they're just estimates, this is probably the issue: it's only considering the first column in the index. Even though it IS, in fact, using the covering index fully, it still has to do a ton of reads on data in the index.

Now I don't know how to optimize this query. This is a log-based table, so the date is crucial, but we have a lot of different values for column2, and there's nothing I can do to optimize for both?

Comment: This may help. MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: That page shows "LIKE" as a range. So looks like only one of those columns in the index would be used...

Comment: You can always create the index and test it. But make sense both are a range.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower What does `EXPLAIN` say when you try this?

Comment: @Barmar I just updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to title question:  Yes.  But that is not your real question, so...

`IN(single_value)` is treated like `= single_value`, so

```
WHERE `col1` IN ('25485') AND `col2` LIKE 'text-%' AND `date` > '2016-06-03 18:13:40'
```

needs one of these:

```
INDEX(col1, col2)
INDEX(col1, date)
```

That is, `col1` needs to be *first*.

`Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort` -- says that the index was 'covering', but it does not say whether the columns were in the optimal order.  That is, one of these is the optimal 'covering' index:

```
INDEX(col1, col2, date)
INDEX(col1, date, col2)
```

I can't predict which will be better, and the Optimizer may or may not predict correctly from its statistics.  But `col1` needs to be first.

If you have

```
col1 IN (123, 234) AND ...
```

*and* you have a new enough version, the Optimizer will efficiently leapfrog through the index -- first do the `123 AND ...`, then do `234 AND ...`.  That is, in *this* case, `IN` works as efficiently as `=`, and can see past `col1` to make use of a 'range' after it.

In "Data Warehouse" type of tables, it is often very efficient to build and maintain [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).  (Since I don't have a feel for the columns or the likely queries, I can't provide details at this time.)

If you are using InnoDB, do you have `innodb_buffer_pool_size` set to about 70% of RAM?  If not, that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Only one index is chosen to access a table.

If you want to make use of all three values, create an index on all three columns:

```
create index myindex on mytable(col1, col2, col3);
```

Try to put the "most specific" column first in the list of columns.

Comment: The index is already on all three columns, and only the first column is being used due to the range scan.

Comment: Not the "most specific" first, the `=` one first.  (Or `IN(single_value)` in this case.)  There could be a zillion rows with `col1 IN ('25485')`, but col1 should still be first.